# Guard from the missing and invalid function params

Tags: javascript

Is there a nicer way to guard all the inputs against missing and invalid param(s)? A long list of `if` statement at the top seems so hard to read.

```
 deliveryForCategory(code, category, dateStart, dateEnd) {
    if (!code) {
      throw Error(ERROR_MISSING_CODE);
    }

    if (!category) {
      throw Error(ERROR_MISSING_CATEGORY);
    }

    if (!DELIVERY_CATEGORIES.has(category)) {
      throw Error(ERROR_INVALID_CATEGORY);
    }

    if (!dateStart || !dateEnd) {
      throw Error(ERROR_MISSING_DATETIME);
    }

    return get(
      `${URL_APP_BASE}/accounts/${code}/delivery/${category}/${dateStart}/${dateEnd}`
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are missing the error handlers, How can we know how to critique the code without knowing how you handle the errors. If they are not caught and just go to the console, halting execution, then this is debugging code. A function should never throw without catch handlers to deal with the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is generally the approach I take; however, if these guards are used a lot throughout the application, perhaps you could refactor them into separate functions:

```
deliveryForCategory(code, category, dateStart, dateEnd) {
    VerifyCode(code);
    VerifyCatergory(category);
    VerifyDate(dateStart);
}
```

Potentially name it something like `ThrowErrorIfCodeInvalid(code)` so it's super clear what it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways I could think of:

```
validateRequired(value, error_code) {
  if (!value)
   throw Error(error_code);
} 

validateCategory(category) {
  if (!DELIVERY_CATEGORIES.has(category)) {
    throw Error(ERROR_INVALID_CATEGORY);
  }
}

deliveryForCategory(code, category, dateStart, dateEnd) {
  validateRequired(code,      ERROR_MISSING_CODE);
  validateRequired(category,  ERROR_MISSING_CATEGORY);
  validateCategory(category);
  validateRequired(dateStart, ERROR_MISSING_DATETIME);
  validateRequird(dateEnd,    ERROR_MISSING_DATETIME); 
  ...
```

or

```
validateRequiredArgs(args, codes) {
  codes.forEach( function(code, index) {
    if (!args[index])
      throw Error(code);
  });
}  

deliveryForCategory(code, category, dateStart, dateEnd) {
   validateArgs(arguments, 
        [ ERROR_MISSING_CODE,
          ERROR_MISSING_CATEGORY,
          ERROR_MISSING_DATETIME,
          ERROR_MISSING_DATETIME ] );
   ...
```